# Is it normal for all of an object's properties to be evaluated on every attribute access?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

Through complete accident and leaving in debugging prints, I've noticed that every time any attribute of my object is accessed, all of its properties are evaluated.

**Is this normal behavior in a standard CPython environment?**

If so, why, and is there any way to stop this behavior?

Comment: Can show example code demonstrating this?  Are you running the code interactively or in any sort of IDE that might be reading the property values to display them in a watch panel or anything like that?

Comment: @BrenBarn Oh, you know what, that might just be it.

Comment: I think I remember something similar being asked about the Spyder IDE a few months ago, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to actually get my module to import through the REPL - even though from my IDE's built-in REPL it works just fine. Huh.

Comment: No, it's not normal behavior, and unless your IDE is being weird, it must be about your overriding `__getattribute__` or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably because your code is being run in an IDE with an integrated debugger, which is re-checking the values of the object's attributes whenever it is accessed. **This is not normal behavior for CPython.**